# C# "How to get a list of match letters words through suggest & append while entering some letters in the datagridview cell?

Tags: c#

When i type the letter G it gives me the list of words that are starting from G. e.g Gas, Grill.

I want to you use the code in my program that can list all the words that have letter G. (You can say match anywhere in the list). Hope i have cleared my query.

Thanking you in anticipation for your kind help.

```cs
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing_1(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        int currentRow = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
        TextBox tb1 = e.Control as TextBox;
        OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [AccName] FROM AccLevel3  WHERE AccName LIKE '" + tb1.Text + "%'", conn);

        conn.Open();
        OleDbDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        AutoCompleteStringCollection AccountCol = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

        if (reader.HasRows == true)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                AccountCol.Add(reader["AccName"].ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data not Found");
        }
        conn.Close();
        reader.Close();

        if (tb1 != null)
        {
            tb1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
            tb1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = AccountCol;
            tb1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        }

        e.Control.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(Column1_KeyPress);
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 2) //Desired Column
        {
            TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
            if (tb != null)
            {
                tb.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(Column1_KeyPress);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please, take a look at [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 1):

Add an extra wildcard to your query to match a suibstring in any position:

`... WHERE AccName LIKE '%" + tb1.Text + "%'" ...`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Since i am a beginner. Can you help me out in sending me the correct position to fit in my code?

Comment: As when i added an extra wild card i got this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @fas1234 ... and what line is throwing that error?  Remember, we can't see your screen.  You need to be specific on what is happening.

Comment: OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [AccName] FROM AccLevel3 WHERE AccName LIKE '%" + tb1.Text + "%'", conn);

Comment: Now the error has resolved but the select query with extra wild card is showing only the list of those words for which the initial letter has typed. e.g If I type G it will give the list of words starting from letter G. I want to get some thing like if I type G,  Fuel & Gas will also come.

Comment: If you run the query `SELECT [AccName] FROM AccLevel3  WHERE AccName LIKE '%G%'` directly on the database, what do you see?